# Recursive call function in jQuery AJAX with  ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function:

```
function primaj(){
$('#tmp').load('msg1.php');
$("#tmp").ajaxStop(function(){
        //do some code
   primaj();
  });
}
```

What I expect is for the load request to run, and when it finishes the function to be called again. But I see that after every call to the function, the next number of calls doubles, from 1 to 2 to 4 to 8 and so on...

My intention is to make a continues load call to the server, but if I use a setInterval command (which works), sometimes the server takes longer to respond, thus the function is called over it's self.

Is there a way to know when the ajax load command has stopped, and then call it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple at this:

```
function primaj() {
    $('#tmp').load('msg1.php', primaj);
}​
```

What you did, is attaching a new callback to run after **every future** ajax completion.
While what my code does is setting a callback to run after the **current** ajax completed.

Comment: That gives some warnings in Chrome continuously for each call

Comment: @Gowtham, what are the warnings you get...? Anyway, the code is valid, and warning doesn't say you got error(or it was an error...) it may say you need to pay attention to what you do because it can be risky.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same in Google Analytics.